# Cookie authentication error using Python requests

Tags: authentication, cookies, python-requests, postman, kibana

I am trying to POST a request to Kibana using the "/api/console/proxy" path.
I have 3 headers in my request:

```
es_headers = {
                'kbn-version': "5.5.0",
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Cookie': "session_2=eyJhbGciOi....(long string)"
            }
```

I am using Python requests as following:

```
session = requests.Session()
r = session.post(url, timeout=15, data=json.dumps(body), headers=es_headers)
```

From "Postman" it works just fine, but from my Python script I get a [200] response but the content of the response is like this:

> 'Error encountered = Unable to decrypt session details from cookie. So
>   clearing it.'

I googled this response but couldn't find any info about it (which is weird ...)
Any help appreciated here
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the cookies separately from the headers, like this:

```
import requests 

es_headers = {
    'kbn-version': "5.5.0",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    }

session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.update({'Cookie': "session_2=eyJhbGciOi....(long string)"})

r = session.post(url, timeout=15, data=json.dumps(body), headers=es_headers)
```

hope this helps